# finding numbers between 2 numbers

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and very new to it and trying to write a simple for loop to print all numbers between two numbers.

e.g 1-4

numbers between 1,4
output

```
2 
3
```

the for loop.

```
int main() {

     int firstNumber;
     int secondNumber;
     std::cout << "Enter first number" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> firstNumber;
     std::cout << "Enter second number" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> secondNumber;

     for (int i=firstNumber; i<secondNumber; i++)  {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the queston?

Answer (score 1):

At the first step of `for` loop execution, `i++` is not applied - and `i` is still equal to 1 (its initial value, defined in `int i = firstNumber` statement. Quoting the [**doc**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#for):

> `for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;`
>
> It works in the following way:
>
> - `initialization` is executed. Generally it is an initial value setting
>     for a counter variable. This is executed only once.
> - `condition` is
>     checked. If it is true the loop continues, otherwise the loop ends and
>     statement is skipped (not executed).
> - `statement` is executed. As usual,
>     it can be either a single statement or a block enclosed in braces { }.
> - finally, whatever is specified in the `increase` field is executed and
>     the loop gets back to step 2.

In your case you can just start the loop from `firstNumber + 1`.

Comment: I edited my codes. probably it isn't very clear of what I want to ask perviously. sorry

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this question as is, frankly speaking, doesn't have much chance to stand against the test of time - it's really basics (not only of C++, but programming in general). Why don't you go through a good tutorial (such as the one linked in my answer) first?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set i to 2 to start the loop?